# jQuery - Flickering when combining slideToggle and animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying use a hidden div and when I press a button to make it visible I want it to "push" away part of another div, in other words the size of the containing div stays the same.

Now, I got this working but the div below the hidden div is flickering, or bouncing up and down a bit. This is likely due to the fact that my animations aren't happening concurrently.

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="button">CLICK</div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="hidden"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width 300px;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
}
#hidden {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
}
#bottom {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $("#button").click(function (e) {
      var newHeight = $("#content").height();
      var hiddenHeight = $("#hidden").outerHeight();
      var visible = $("#hidden").is(":visible");

      newHeight += (visible ? hiddenHeight : -hiddenHeight);

      $("#hidden").slideToggle({
          duration: 200,
          queue: false
      });

      $("#content").animate({
          height: newHeight
      }, {
          duration: 200,
          queue: false
      });
  });
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2exxrs1n/

Do you have any idea how to fix this, or an alternative solution to my problem?

Comment: I see it smoothly.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it because jquery animations are not perfectly synchronized.
Maybe try considering CSS3 transitions.

```
transition-duration: 0.5s;
```

I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2exxrs1n/3/) here with an example